# html refresh properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible that the html page loaded, cannot be refreshed or reloaded by the user

Thanks..

Comment: What is the problem that you want to solve? Why do you want to prevent a user from reloading a page?

Comment: Advertisement spammers attempt this type of thing, "Keep me visible no matter what" where you basically just have to "kill" the web page - REALLY ticks people off and presents an "anti-attitude" to whatever is being presented.  One major travel&hospitality site did something similar - I killed my account and NEVER went back.

Comment: Well, to give The Hulk the benefit of the doubt, and to acknowledge the fact that the question is questionably phrased, it may be something innocuous like a form submit confirmation screen. Preventing reload may be a bad idea, but there's a chance that there's a non-obnoxious underlying goal.

Comment: Hi,So lets say if i  am hosting a small application like online exams or a quiz and there are timers running on the page.And if the user refreshes the page all the properties on the web page should be handled again.This in turn causes extra code to be written.That is the reason for this question to be asked..

Comment: Also we had done this once where the page refreshes by itself every minute and user also refreshes the page and the handling of the page functionality and the code written didn't bring up the quality in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [onbeforeunload](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm) event could be used to detect a situation like this.

I think this is what SO uses when you write an answer and then want to leave before you post it; it asks you if you are sure.

Is that what you want to use it for or what?

Comment: I will assume that this is a client-server application and not just a static page with JavaScript that takes care of everything. If that is the case, you could manage the timer server side. That will be immune to page refreshes by the user since the timer will be running outside of the reach of the client. You have more control on the server than the client, so the code should be easier (cleaner) to write.

Comment: Yes this is a client-server app and it is django .I will try with the server side coding in this case.Thanks.......

Answer (score 10):

No, **and you shouldn't try to do this**...it breaks all the users expectations of what a webpage does.

Whether it's code or behavior, when you're having trouble doing something, it's usually because it hasn't been done or hasn't been made easy...stop to ask *why* that is, and often you'll find there's a good reason.

Comment: And I will add that if you are writing a web "application" then you *must* gracefully handle the case where the user hits refresh at an inconvenient time. It will happen.

Comment: Nick Please see my comment above